# WPF textbox OnSourceUpdate for each char input

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a wpf window with a textbox and a property in the viewmodel called Val

```
<Textbox Binding={Path=Val, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}>
```

The problem is that val only updates once the control loses focus and not for each char I input.

Anyone has any idea how can I update Val for each input at the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following

```
<Textbox Binding={Path=Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>
```

The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` of a TextBox is `LostFocus`.
If you set it to `PropertyChanged` it will trigger on every Char you change.